# How to import time machine backup music (or from iphone) to ventura?

Tags: itunes, backup, time-machine, migration, ventura

I was using macbook with osx maverick and had library in Music.app (~/Music). I replaced this laptop with new one on M1 and did fresh Ventura install on it.

Everything is good except my music library: even after doing `rm -rf ~/Music` and copying this directory from TimeMachine backup doesn't work, Music.app still can't find all my music playlists even if i use Open menu (cmd+o).

How can i restore it? Did i miss any hidden directory or something like this?

Btw, i have an iPhone that was synced with old system and has all orzanised as needed. Maybe, it can help? Can i import from iphone to mac?

Comment: If it is a Time Machine backup is there a reason you are not just using Time Machine to restore your old music library?

Comment: @SteveChambers, i already restored `~/Music` directory from TM backup to new system. But music app didn't see it and says everything is empty. That's why i posted here.

Comment: and you have done this? https://support.apple.com/guide/music/import-items-already-on-your-computer-mus3081/mac

Comment: Did you restore ~/Music/Music Library.musiclibrary

Comment: @mmmmmm, no, it doesn't exists because they have different database format now.

Comment: @SteveChambers, yes, i've tried this as stated in post. Used "Open" and "Import" options from menu and it didn't worked.

Comment: So where was the metadata held - the one I gave is Venture - the older was in ~/Music/iTunes

Comment: @mmmmmm, "Ventura" – is the name of new mac osx v13.

Comment: @mmmmmm, old library was in `~/Music/iTunes/` directory, yes. New is in `~/Music/{library_name}/Music Library.musiclibrary` file.

Comment: I don't need to convert it somehow manually – just open old XML with option special key is enough.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, found this solution and it's pretty simple.

At first, using "Open" and "Import" options from menu as suggested in Apple support website didn't worked. Copy whole `~/Music` directory from TimeMachine backup didn't worked too – still empty Music app.

Found out, that i need to quit Music.app, then hold "option" key and click on app to open it. In dialog box "Choose library" and navigate to `ITL` file (warn: **not** `XML`!). It asked for a library name – need to give different that was in backup files.

It took some time to organise files but finally i have all playlists that was before.